# JSF / RichFaces commandButton called by JavaScript does not redirect

Tags: javascript, jsf, redirect, richfaces, submit

I have a javascript function to run h: or a4j: commanButton. When javascript function is called, action button runs action but after that page is not redirected.
I am using Seam 2.2 and RichFaces 3.3.3
What is the problem here? Thanks.

```
  function submitForm(){
        document.getElementById('myForm:save').click(); 

        // does not redirect.
        //document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
        }
```

Even if I use submit() page is not redirected.

Form:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
//some fields

<h:commandButton id="save" value="Save"
                         action="#{personHome.persist}" />

</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the point, the following should work for `<h:commandButton>`:

```
document.getElementById('myForm:save').click();
```

and when the button is the **first** button of the form in question:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

You only need to ensure that the generated client ID is exactly the same as the ID which you're specifying in `getElementById()`. If the `<h:form>` is by itself nested in another `UINamingContainer` component, then the ID will be prepended with its ID. Rightclick page in browser and *View Source* to be sure.

As to the concrete problem, perhaps you've attached this function to another button which in turn also submits some form by itself which will result in a race condition of two requests. You should then `return false;` from or after the function to block the caller's default action. E.g.

```
<h:commandButton onclick="return submitForm();" />
```

with

```
function submitForm(){
    // ...

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. It worked for a4j: also for h:commandButton.